# How can I check whether time from model object created time is over 10mins?

Tags: python, django

**models.py**

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class UserAuthToken(models.Model):

    email = models.ForeignKey(UserSubEmail)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=34, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "AuthToken for %s" % self.email
```

I want to check elapsed time between token's created time and now So if token created before more than 10 minutes, I can recognize this token is invalid.

**views.py**

```
def create_email_confirm_key(request, uid, token):
    try:
        user_authtoken = UserAuthToken.objects.get(uid=uid)
    except (TypeError, ValueError, OverflowError, User.DoesNotExist):
        user_authtoken = None

    if not 'user_authtoken is created before more than 10minutes' :
        This token is valid and do something
```

How can I check whether time between `the token created` and `now` is more than 10mins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always calculate the delta from the current time using [`django.utils.timezone`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.timezone):

```
from django.utils.timezone import now, timedelta

if now() - user_authtoken.created <= timedelta(seconds=10*60):
    # token valid
```

But I recommend you take a look at django's [Cryptographic signing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signing/#module-django.core.signing). It lets you [verify timestamped signatures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/signing/#verifying-timestamped-values) and handles all the delta calculations for you.